# LoadError: no such file to load -- glib2.so

Tags: ruby, user-interface, gtk2

I just installed gtk2 and inteded to follow a tutorial but get `LoadError: no such file to load -- glib2.so` when I `require 'gtk2'`.

```
irb(main):005:0> require 'gtk2'
LoadError: no such file to load -- glib2.so
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/glib2-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/glib2.rb:101
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gtk2-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/gtk2/base.rb:12
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gtk2-2.0.0-x86-mingw32/lib/gtk2.rb:11
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
    from C:/ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from (irb):5
```

ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]

gtk2 (2.0.0 x86-mingw32)

How to fix this error?

Comment: did you just install the gem or did you install both the library and the gem?

Comment: I did `gem install gtk2` but I can see `glib2` right above `gtk2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I downloaded and installed the `ruby-gnome2-0.16.0-1-i386-mswin32.exe` from the [Ruby-GNOME2 install guide page](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/?Install%20Guide%20for%20Windows) it is now working.